# How to store metadata derived from Named Entity Recognition (NER) in MongoDB documents?

Tags: mongodb

I have collection of news articles in this format:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId
    "author" : 
    "title" : 
    "description" : 
    "url" : 
    "urlToImage" : 
    "publishedAt" : 
    "content" : 
    "source" : 
}
```

My plan is to run NER against the collection to tag the articles with various meta data such as companies mentioned, specified products, sentiment, geolocation, etc.

The long-term plan is to build a GraphQL API frontend and be able to search (Elasticsearch) or query the DB by the metadata.

My question is what’s the best format to store the metadata that would be best for querying a GraphQL API? My initial thought is store the metadata as a subdocuments like below, or maybe a entire different collection just for metadata:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId
    "author" : 
    "title" : 
    "description" : 
    "url" : 
    "urlToImage" : 
    "publishedAt" : 
    "content" : 
    "source" : 
    "metadata" : {
        "_id" : 
        "organization" : 
        "products" : 
        "sentiment" : 
        "location" : 
        "topics" : 
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. We appreciate your participation. Please consider reading the following article: _[How do I ask a good question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (Help Centre)_. Currently your question is asking for opinions on a topic and these questions aren't very suitable for this site. Your question might be closed as [**primarily opinion-based**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). Consider adding more details to your [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/233793/edit) (if possible).